# Let $N$ = $11^2 \times 13^4 \times 17^6$. How many positive factors of $N^2$ are less than $N$ but not a factor of $N$?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, factoring

Let $N$ = $11^2 \times 13^4 \times 17^6$. How many positive factors of $N^2$ are less than $N$ but not a factor of $N$?

$Approach$:

$N$=$11^2$.$13^4$.$17^6$

$N^2$=$11^4$.$13^8$.$17^{12}$

This means $N$ has $(2+1) * (4+1) * (6+1)  = 105$ factors and $N^2$ has $ (4+1) * (8+1) * (12+1) = 585 $ factors.

Therefore, there are 480 numbers that are not a factor of N. They are any combination of :
$11^3$,$11^4$,$13^5$,$13^6$,$13^7$,$13^8$,$17^7$,$17^8$,$17^9$,$17^{10}$,$17^{11}$,$17^{12}$.

But how many of these combinations are less than N?  Not really sure how to do that in a easy way.

Please guide me how to do so.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is a current problem on brilliant.org.

Comment: @ErickWong: when does it expire?

Answer (score 4):

If a divisor $d$ of $N^2$ is smaller than $N$ then $\frac{N^2}{d}$ is a divisor of $N^2$ larger than $N$. 

Let's say that there are $n$ divisors of $N^2$ that are smaller than $N$. Then there are $n$ divisors of $N^2$ that are larger than $N$.
In total there are 585 divisors of $N^2$ and each one is either smaller, larger or equal to $N$.
 
From these you should be able to find $n$.

Now $480$ divisors of $N^2$ do not divide $N$ and $n$ of them are larger than $N$ (some explanation here) therefore $480-n$ of them are smaller than $N$.

Comment: Sir, can you please explain how answer is 292?

Comment: so, is the answer 188?

Comment: You mean $N^2 \over d$ is larger than $N$ ?

Comment: @arbautjc: Thanks!!!

Comment: @P.. can you give a working?

Comment: i am unable to get to the answer.

Comment: You have $585$ divisors of $N^2$. One of them is $N$, and the other $584$ come in pairs $\left\langle d,\frac{N^2}x\right\rangle$, where one member of the pair is less than $N$ and the other is greater than $N$. Thus, $N^2$ has $\frac{584}2=292$ divisors that are less than $N$ and $292$ that are greater. $105$ of the $293$ divisors of $N^2$ that are $\le N$ are also divisors of $N$, so there are indeed $188$ divisors of $N^2$ that are $\le N$ but not divisors of $N$. There are also $292$ divisors of $N^2$ that are $>N$ and therefore not divisors of $N$.

Answer (score 0):

N= 11^2 * 13^4 * 17^6
No of Factors of N = 3*5*7 = 105
There will be one factor which is N, So remaining = 105-1 = 104

No of factors of N^2= 5*9*13 = 585, of these N will be one of the factors.
Out of the remaining 584 factors, half will be less than N and half will be grater than N , So no. of factors of N^2 which are less than N= 584/2= 292

Hence the number of factors of N^2 are less than N but not a factor of N = 292-104= 188